# How can i multiselect in django admin dropdown on foreignkey data just like manytomanyfield?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Images(models.Model):

    def upload_path(instance, filename):
        return '/images/'.join([filename])

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    logits = models.BinaryField()
    #customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer ,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Images ,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer_id)
```

My problem is i want to be able to assign multiple images to single user which should be possible because of ForeignKey but i don't seem to get it to work like that.

I want multiselect field just like in manytomanyfield but in foreignkey field.

Comment: That makes no sense, since a `ForeignKey` can only select a *single* item... A `ForeignKey` means that a `Customer` points to a *single* `Images` object.

Comment: is there a way to create one to many relation in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is [I] want to be able to assign multiple images to [a] single user which should be possible because of `ForeignKey` but [I] don't seem to get it to work like that.

**No**: A `ForeignKey` is a *many-to-one* relation: it means that *many* `Customer`s can refer to a, possibly the same, single `Images`. If you want to use multiple `Image`s then you need to write the `ForeignKey` in the opposite direction, so:

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):

    def upload_path(instance, filename):
        return f'/images/{filename}'

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    logits = models.BinaryField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Customer',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='images'
    )

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer_id}'
```